# How to set fixed space between columns with different height with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have a nice grid of items on my site using Bootstrap 3 grid, while each item has a different height.
The problem is that i get different spaces between the items.
Forgive me for the long code, I had to write 6 items in order to show the problem. Once you read the first  you'll notice it repeats but with different length due to different item description.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="result-padder">
                <div class="box">
                    <p class="boxTitle">vendor1</p>
                    <p class="boxDescription">Description of vendor1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="result-padder">
                <div class="box">
                    <p class="boxTitle">vendor2</p>
                    <p class="boxDescription">Description of vendor2 which is longer and the layout takes more than one line...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="result-padder">
                <div class="box">
                    <p class="boxTitle">vendor3</p>
                    <p class="boxDescription">Description of vendor3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="result-padder">
                <div class="box">
                    <p class="boxTitle">vendor4</p>
                    <p class="boxDescription">Description of vendor4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="result-padder">
                <div class="box">
                    <p class="boxTitle">vendor5</p>
                    <p class="boxDescription">Description of vendor5</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="result-padder">
                <div class="box">
                    <p class="boxTitle">vendor6</p>
                    <p class="boxDescription">Description of vendor6</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The result is that the first row is set right but the second row comes out bad. 
I want the spaces between all items to be the same, making it much more fluid.

Note: the heights of the items change all the time, so it has to work with all set of heights.

Take a look at it, you need to resize the result window to max in order to see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/asafusan/09egpzkj/6/

How can I fix it?
I'm a rookie in programing so please explain extensively.

Thanks

Comment: There's no `row-fluid` class in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: add a jsfiddle and we might help you solve it

Comment: here's a jsfiddle, in order to see it right you need to resize the result window to max: http://jsfiddle.net/asafusan/09egpzkj/6/

Answer (score 0):

i happen some time if you put less data then other so it become some irregular shape, 
for this you have to give a fix height to your div, but it cause one issue that is it will be in same height in mobile or tablet as your applied,
so for this you have use media queries for mobile version
i am declaring another class that is grid, and give static height

Comment: I want it to work with different heights, for example: http://www.theknot.com/weddings/photos/orange    or: http://www.lasso.co.il/

Comment: i should be like, if u have a div with name of '<div class="abc">some content</div>'   the your css will be like '.abc{height:2oopx; min-height:100px' by this you are forcing a div to achieve the this height,

Comment: but I want the divs to have different heights

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, I would use a visual border to see the code. I created a mockup for you here

```
[http://www.bootply.com/Pzn15AfwyA][1] 



.container {
      border: 1px solid blue;
      }

    .result-padder {
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">

            <div class="result-padder">
            <h1>vendor1</h1>
            <p>Description of vendor1</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">

            <div class="result-padder">
            <h1>vendor1</h1>
            <p>Description of vendor1</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">

            <div class="result-padder">
            <h1>vendor1</h1>
            <p>Description of vendor1</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div><!-- .row 1 -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">

            <div class="result-padder">
            <h1>vendor1</h1>
            <p>Description of vendor1</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">

            <div class="result-padder">
            <h1>vendor1</h1>
            <p>Description of vendor1</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">

            <div class="result-padder">
            <h1>vendor1</h1>
            <p>Description of vendor1</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div><!-- .row 2 -->



      </div>
    </div>


  [1]: http://www.bootply.com/Pzn15AfwyA
```

Comment: you are right, I should add border to get a better look at the result. I'm not sure if you tried to solve my problem, however if you add more text to vendor2 so that there's more than one line in it's description, the result is that the spaces between all vendors are not the same